# collision detect don't get the collisions

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to develop collision between 2 sprites, but I'm not getting it to be done.
I'm scheduling a selector to verify the collision, and another one to generate the enemy sprite. The problem is that they are not colliding.

```
this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::addenemy),2);
this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::collisionEnemy),2);
```

I'm scheduling both selectors as above, but if I try to schedule collisionEnemy with a value less than 2 (smaller than addEnemy timer), then I get an error:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

And if I put a value of 2 or more, the identifier doesn't get the collision

This is the collisionEnemy selector:

```
void HelloWorld::collisionEnemy(float dt)
{
    CCSprite *player = (CCSprite*)getChildByTag(1);
    CCSprite *enemy = (CCSprite*)getChildByTag(3);

    CCRect playerRect = CCRectMake(
                                   player->getPosition().x - (player->getContentSize().width/2),
                                   player->getPosition().y - (player->getContentSize().height/2),
                                   player->getContentSize().width,
                                   player->getContentSize().height);

    CCRect miniBarrierRect = CCRectMake(
                                   enemy->getPosition().x - (enemy->getContentSize().width/2),
                                   enemy->getPosition().y - (enemy->getContentSize().height/2),
                                   enemy->getContentSize().width,
                                   enemy->getContentSize().height);

    if (playerRect.intersectsRect(enemyRect)) {

        CCLog("enemy Collision");

    } else {

        CCLog("not enemy Collision");
        }



    }
```

Comment: Is it the collision detection that doesn't work or the scheduling?

Comment: Probably the schedulling, if the value is greater than 2, than it runs, but it doesn't collide because it doesn't run in the correct frame

Comment: have you tried `boundingbox()`? I mostly use that and it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want true collision detection, I think you should look into Box2D

Very simple collision detection:

```
cocos2d::Vector2 p = touch->getLocation();

cocos2d::Rect rect = _sprite->getBoundingBox();

if(rect.containsPoint(p))
{
    // collision
}
else
{
    // no collision
}
```

your warning `libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile` is just that. Some tools like Photoshop embed bad ICCP chunks. If you have ImageMagick you can easily get rid of the warning

`find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec convert {} -strip {} \;`

Before you run the above command *make* sure you know where you are running it from. Restrict to just where your game resources are perhaps..Always backup first.

Comment: I'm getting no type named 'vector2' in namespace 'cocos2d'

Comment: it has been changed to `cocos1d::Vec2` See: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/CHANGELOG